# Convert list of str into list of int

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

So my list of str is:

```
col = ['cat1','cat2','cat3']
```

I want to convert into list of int like:

```
col = [0,1,2]
```

I tried:

```
col=pd.Series(col)
col=pd.to_numeric(col)
```

But it gives error:

Unable to parse string "cat1" at position 0

Comment: Use `col = [i for i,j in enumerate(col)]`

Comment: What kind of conversion is this? Just position?

Comment: What is desired output if `col = ['cat4','cat2','cat3', 'cat2']` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [4719]: pd.Series(col).astype('category').cat.codes
Out[4719]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int8
```

Or,

```
In [4726]: pd.Series(pd.factorize(col)[0])
Out[4726]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Or,

```
In [4738]: np.unique(col, return_inverse=True)[1]
Out[4738]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Or,

```
In [4739]: pd.Categorical(col).codes
Out[4739]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int8)
```

---

Use `.tolist()` in the end, if you need as list.

Comment: Got it nice one

Comment: pd.Categorical, np.unique work on sort, not pd.factorize by default.

Comment: How is it wrong from what OP asked? Matches with what was asked. Nor asked for sorted factors.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
print (pd.factorize(col)[0].tolist())
[0, 1, 2]
```

If not duplicate values:

```
a = list(range(len(col)))
[0, 1, 2]
```

Also it working nice if change `col` to:

```
col = ['cat4','cat2','cat3', 'cat2']
print (pd.factorize(col)[0].tolist())
[0, 1, 2, 1]
```

Also get different output with second solution:

```
col = ['cat4','cat2','cat3', 'cat2']
a = list(range(len(col)))
print (a)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `groupby+ngroup` i.e

```
col = ['cat1','cat2','cat3', 'cat2']
col=pd.Series(col)

col.groupby(col).ngroup()
```

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    1
dtype: int64
```

If you need list then

```
col.groupby(col).ngroup().tolist()
[0, 1, 2, 1]
```